# Where is ros2doctor?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through the tutorials on dashing distro. Up to this point (mostly) ok, but this is baffling. I am at the "Getting started with ros2doctor", but "doctor" or "wtf" do not exist as a ros2 command. It is not included in the command list from "ros2 -h" either (and neither is in the example output in earlier tutorial!). So why should it even be available? (ubuntu 18, binary version). Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355129/where-is-ros2doctor?/) by [Almost](https://answers.ros.org/users/28007/almost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros2doctor was released in eloquent and likely is not backported to dashing, the feature list for eloquent is [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Eloquent-Elusor/)

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3